# How can I determine the value of very rare cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I recently bought a large collection of very old Magic cards. While sorting through them, I found two cards that I don't have an immediate answer for their value.

[image: Pro Tour 1996 Winter Orb Front]
[image: Pro Tour 1996 Winter Orb Back]
(Promo from the first Pro Tour, in 1996)
[image: Autographed Revised Blue Ward]
(Autographed Blue Ward (might be Dan Frazier, revised))

Google / magiccards.info didn't have any information.

tcgplayer.com came up with [this result](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic/collectors-edition/winter-orb-ce), a 'Collectors Edition' Winter Orb,
but that page says that the card type is 'Continuous Artifact' and has different text for the ability.

Is there a concrete way to determine the values of these cards?

Comment: I wish I could go back in time -- the idea of Blue Ward being a "Very Rare Card" is mind blowing.

Comment: I interpret this as asking how to assess rare cards (the kind that there isn't necessarily obvious price history for on all the big sites), where these specific cards are really just examples, which seems like a totally reasonable question. That said, the accepted answer doesn't really answer the general question, which makes it look like this question really was just "what are these cards worth?", which indeed doesn't seem great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gold-bordered cards are from [World Championship decks](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/World_Championship_Decks). They have been printed in large numbers and are not legal to play in any format, so their monetary value is probably very low.

The Blue Ward might have value due to the signature, but since it's not a highly sought after card, I wouldn't expect too much either.

Comment: While you've helped give values for the cards, I don't see how this answer actually answers the question of "Is there a concrete way to determine the values of these cards?"

Answer (score 3):

The only way to attempt to determine a concrete value for a card is to find it's price in a large market place where market forces (supply & demand) have determined the value of the listed cards.

Europe's biggest trading site, [magiccardmarket.eu](http://magiccardmarket.eu), is very comprehensive in the cards that it lists. They have one of the best listings of uncommon sets.
There the winter orb from the World Championship Deck's in near mint condition is ~2€

As my predecessor already mentioned, it is not tournament legal (only white and black bordered cards are).

Nevertheless, gold border cards are a cheap alternative for players building a draft-cube or for any other non-tournament use.